# About netty's http request handling

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to study netty. I've created a small server application that  redirects ulr's .
Server Code :
`

```
if (urlDecoder.path().equals("/redirect")) {
    FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    response.headers().set(LOCATION, urlDecoder.parameters().get("url").get(0));
    response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());

    if (!keepAlive) {
        ctx.write(response).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    } else {
        response.headers().set(CONNECTION, Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
        ctx.write(response);
    }
}
```

It worked, but yesterday I want to upgrade it and add some code like this

```
String redirectionUrl = urlDecoder.parameters().get("url").get(0);

if (!redirectStatistics.containsKey(redirectionUrl)) {
    redirectStatistics.put(redirectionUrl, 1);
} else {
    int tempValue = redirectStatistics.get(redirectionUrl).intValue();
    redirectStatistics.put(redirectionUrl, tempValue++);
}
```

And then it has been broken.
Please help to understand what happened.

Comment: What you mean with broken ? Any exceptions etc ?